# Windows, имя файла при перетаскивании в консоль

Tags: windows, консоль

Почему в **Windows** при перетаскивании файлов в консоль их имена в некоторых случаях обрамляются кавычками, а в некоторых - нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если имя файла содержит пробелы - в консоли оно появится в кавычках.